# Single endpoint post array with multiple type of dictionary

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating the `RESTful` endpoints for supporting `frontend` payload.
My payload is an order of `build your own` dish and `ready-made single dish`

**Problem:**
In single `POST` of `frontend`. He wants to put everything to the single time. That's mean in the given `list` will contains 2 types of dictionary
one for `build your own` and one for `ready-made single dish`

**IMO:**
He can `POST` 2 times for each type of payload. By this method the endpoint will do one thing and I prefer that way.

He has only 1 reason to `POST` everything to single endpoint

**Question:**
What is your best practice for this sort of problem?

**Build Your Own Payload:**
In short I call it BYO.
1. `base_bowl` will dictates the `size` and `price` of the item
1. `base_bowl` will also determine the number of `fishes`, `toppings`, `sauces`. 
Because `base_bowl` size S, M, or L has different quota.

For example

Size S can has `fishes` 1 scoop size S, and `toppings` 2 scoops size S.

Size M can has `fishes` 2 scoops size M, and `toppings` 3 scoops size M.
 Then if the customer would like to add more than quota he must add it in the `extra_fishes`, `extra_toppings`
Base on `Price` id since `quantity` is determine by number of member in the list.

```
  {
        "base_bowl": salad.id,  # require=True, Price id
        "fishes": [salmon.id, tuna.id],
        "extra_fishes": [tofu.id],
        "toppings": [tamago.id, mango.id],
        "extra_toppings": [rambutan.id],
        "premium_toppings": [ikura.id],
        "sauces": [shoyu.id, spicy_kimchi.id],
        "extra_sauces": [],
        "sprinkles": [sesame.id, fried_shalots.id],
        "dish_order": 1,  # require=True
        "note": {
            'msg': 'eat here',
        },
    }
```

And backend will validate the input and INSERT them to `Order` and `OrderItem`

**Ready-Made Dish:**
This is very straight forward because it has no implicit logic like `BYO`. It just add `OrderItem` to `Order`

Use `Menu` id, size, and `qty` to determine price. Because customer is free to choose

```
{
    'order_items': [
        {
            'menu_id': has_poink_menu.id,
            'size': Price.MenuSize.XL,  # 27, 37, 47, 52
            'qty': 2,  # amount = 52 * 2
        },
        {
            'menu_id': no_poink_menu.id,
            'size': Price.MenuSize.L,  # 20, 30, 40, 45
            'qty': 1  # amount = 40 * 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The fewer transactions the better, in my opinion. Many webpages load slowly not because of the size of the content, but the number of requests that need to be made for all the resources. OTOH, your API design may trump that concern. That said, your situation is somewhat unclear. It's hard to understand what the context of `build your own` and `ready-made` are; why is it important to you that these are separated? If it's relevant, consider posting some code of your endpoints.

Comment: @sytech I have provided my detail please give me your comment

Comment: @sytech I just realize that I can add nested layer more. Then different payload will be classified by key. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: i believe you can make a custom serializer for this case but you need to pass an option for to make a conditional call if one is for `serializerA` or  `serializerB`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is opinionated, but to me a RESTful design is kept much clearer by keeping endpoints specific and well defined.  So in your case there may be a `BYODishViewSet` and `ReadyMadeDishViewSet` mapped to `/api/byodish/` and `/api/readymadedish/`.

However, if this is part of a larger single model, say an `Order` model, then you may want to consider using a nested (writable) serializer to wrap up an Order as a single API request-response.

Comment: Yes. I had tried 1 endpoint contains multiple dictionary. It is webhook from facebook which is very horrible. One list contains 3 or more nested 3 level dictionaries. However, that's is a facebook webhook not human in my team. I cannot do anything to let it change, but this time is is my teammate. I can ask him to help the endpoint

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got the idea now by adding one more nested layer. Then I can centralized the payload.